# How to associate "delete" event with button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I know that I can use "Delete" link in gridview but in my case it doesn't fit .
I marked my deleting button.

[image]

Comment: I don't speak Russian, so forgive me if the answer is obvious:  how does the app know what row you want to delete?

Comment: I don't know so that is why I asked this question.

Comment: Perhaps I was unclear:  what I meant was, "How does the user indicate what row they want to delete?"  Or does the button say something like, "Delete last row"?

Comment: I think it's possible to associate events in gridview with external controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to make a row in the grid selectable and do an onclicke event for the delete button. Make it delete the selected row in the grid and the rowdeleting event will be fired.

You can't bind the button directly to the rowdeleting event.

Answer (score 1):

use command field instead of link button. Or even you can use css which looks like a button.